# Duplicate Key Update using primary key

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to update the `postmeta` table in WP. I am using the below query to set a new row. However, if that row already exists, I just want to update the `meta_value`. At the moment, each time I run it, it keeps adding a new row for each `product[0]` even if it already exists.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ($productID[0], 'custom_field', 'worked') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = 'changed'"; 
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( $sql )
);
```

When I dump the last query, it gives me the below which I cant seem to see what is wrong.

```
"INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (1836, 'custom_field', 'worked') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE meta_value = 'changed'"
```

Comment: Please, take time to read what you post. When you wish someone to help you, show some respect by avoiding typo errors in the text.

Answer (score 0):

This would occur if you haven't defined a unique or primary index on the table.  Presumably, you want only one row per `post_id`/`meta_key` combination.

Try adding this:

```
create unique index idx_wp_postmeta_2 on wp_postmeta(post_id, meta_key)
```

Then your query should update the value rather than inserting a new row.

Comment: Thanks Gordon but where would I enter this?

Comment: @Matt . . . You would run it in the database, say through phpadmin.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you are updating postmeta table using custom query ?

while you can achieve same thing using WordPress's built-in function.

**[update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)** is built-in function which will update row if exists in table otherwise, it will add new entry.

You can check it by **[get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)** function.

e.g.

```
if(get_post_meta($productID[0], 'custom_field', true) == 'worked') {
    update_post_meta($productID[0], 'custom_field', 'changed');
}
```